# Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

codes --> https://github.com/furkannzmnn/CreateResume/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/resume/DataAcces/ResumeDao.java

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resumeManager' defined in file [C:\Users\furkan\IdeaProjects\Resume\target\classes\com\example\resume\Business\concretes\ResumeManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resumeDao' defined in com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ResumeApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.example.resume.ResumeApplication.main(ResumeApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resumeDao' defined in com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ResumeApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.resume.DataAcces.ResumeDao.getResumeDto()!
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTO name should be fully qualified and Entity class should be provided inside the query to join tables with Hibernate.

```
 @Query("select new com.example.resume.Entity.Dto.ResumeDto (a.experienceName, e.schoolName,e.firstYear, e.endYear, a.experienceDescription) " +
            "from Resume j ,Education e , Experience a where j.experience.id=a.id and j.education.id=e.id")
 List<ResumeDto> getResumeDto();
```